# How to Do Jquery equivalent of prevAll() nextAll() in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm building a project using AngularJS and can't seem to find any example of what I'm looking for...

Using AngularJS, I know how to add a class to anything that's clicked, but how do I add a class to all previous items and remove class from all next items?

I'd like to do the jquery equivalent of .prevAll()/.nextAll(), but using AngularJS.

Here's and example of the jquery way for reference:

HTML:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary"> Progress 1</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary"> Progress 2</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary"> Progress 3</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary"> Progress 4</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary"> Progress 5</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary"> Progress 6</a>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".btn").on("click", function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).prevAll().addClass('active');
    $(this).nextAll().removeClass('active');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mujaji/yy82twho/1/

I'm trying to figure out how to do using AngularJS. Can someone explain a good strategy or standard?

thanks
Joe

Comment: what did you try so far? please post your attempts in angular.

Comment: how are your `a` tag generated? i assume it is from ng-repeat. Share our angular code.

Comment: you'll need to create a `btn` directive

Comment: I'm basically following a similar implementation as this demo from Scotch: [http://embed.plnkr.co/M03tYgtfqNH09U4x5pHC/preview]

Comment: Only problem is I want to previous step to be highlighted, as well as current step. I didn't look into doing with a directive, so I can research that concept.

Comment: I'm familiar with Jquery way to do it, but can't find an example using AngularJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As all the `<a>` have same structue so i am assuming it is generated by `ng-repeat`.

You can do this by using the $index of ng-repeat in angularjs as below

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" ng-class="{'active': $index <= selectedIndex}" 
         ng-repeat="p in progress" ng-click="click($index)"> {{p}}</a>
```

`active` class will be automatically added and removed to a tag based on the condition given in `ng-class`

`selectedIndex` is set in the controller based on the `<a>` clicked.

In the controller you will have somthing like below.

```
  $scope.progress = ['Progress 1','Progress 2','Progress 3','Progress 4','Progress 5','Progress 6'];

  $scope.selectedIndex = 0;

  $scope.click = function(indexclicked){
    $scope.selectedIndex = indexclicked;
  }
```

Here is the working Jsfiddle demo i have created : http://jsfiddle.net/Makarand_Patil/U3pVM/34638/

Hope this helps you.

Comment: exactly what I've been looking for! Thanks @Makarand_Patil